# Lists construction in Python Bytecode

Tags: python, bytecode, cpython

This python code:

```
import dis
def f():
    a=[1,2,3]

dis.dis(f)
```

generates this output:

```
  2           0 RESUME                   0

  3           2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ((1, 2, 3))
              6 LIST_EXTEND              1
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

I am confused about the array building process.

My guess is that:

- `BUILD_LIST 0` sets a marker, or maybe a placeholder for the list's pointer?.
- `LOAD_CONST 1` puts all the elements of the #1 constant (that happens to be that tuple), one at the time from the last to the first in the machine stack.
- `LIST_EXTEND 1` pops and adds one element from the machine stack at the time to the list, until reaching the marker (I don't know what the `1` would be for).
- `STORE_FAST` now we have the pointer on top, so this instruction finally binds the pointer to the #0 identifier that happens to be `a`.

Is this correct? (edit: no, the guess is incorrect)

Comment: so the size of each element in the PVM stack is variable? (one element can hold a whole tuple)

Comment: oh, so what gets in the stack is actually a pointer to the tuple constant, right?

Comment: Please don't use `<strike>` to signal that your original understanding is wrong. Write an answer instead.

Comment: "Edit" is not much better. See e.g. *[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)* (near *"Changelogs"*). The question should appear as if it was written right now (without invalidating answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cpython executes its bytecodes in a stack-based virtual machine.
Now let's start explaining the `dis` output line-by line.

- `BUILD_LIST  0`

Here `BUILD_LIST` is the `opcode` and `0` is the `oparg`. This will create an empty list and push it onto the top of the stack.

```c
case TARGET(BUILD_LIST): {
    PyObject *list =  PyList_New(oparg); // create empty list
    if (list == NULL)
        goto error;
    // Skipped other parts of the code for brevity.
    PUSH(list); // push it onto the top of the stack
    DISPATCH();
}
```

After this operation the stack state will be

| stack |
| --- |
| list(a pointer to PyObject) |

- `LOAD_CONST  1`

This will [pushes `(1, 2, 3)`(ie, `co_consts[1]`) to the top of the stack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CONST).

```c
case TARGET(LOAD_CONST): {
     PREDICTED(LOAD_CONST);
     PyObject *value = GETITEM(consts, oparg);
     Py_INCREF(value);
     PUSH(value);
     DISPATCH();
}
```

stack state has now changed to

| stack |
| --- |
| (1, 2, 3) |
| list(a pointer to PyObject) |

- `LIST_EXTEND 1`

This will first `pop` the iterable from
the top of the stack(which is `(1, 2, 3)`).
`PEEK(oparg)` will then get the `oparg`th(which is 1) element of the stack without removing it(which is the `list` object).

`PEEK(n)` expands to `#define PEEK(n) (stack_pointer[-(n)])`

```
case TARGET(LIST_EXTEND): {
     PyObject *iterable = POP();
     PyObject *list = PEEK(oparg);
     PyObject *none_val = _PyList_Extend((PyListObject *)list, iterable); 
     // Skipped other parts of the code for brevity.
     Py_DECREF(none_val);
     Py_DECREF(iterable);
     DISPATCH();
}
```

The `_PyList_Extend` API extends the list with the iterable in-place

Now the stack state would be:

| stack |
| --- |
| list(Now populated with 1, 2, 3) |

- `STORE_FAST`

Stores [`STACK.pop()` into the local variable `a`(`co_varnames\[var_num\]`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Does the PVM stack at any time hold anything other than pointers or basic types like integers?